# Testing for Resources such as Drawables and Background

Tags: android, conditional-statements, android-resources

I need to see if there is a way where I can test for what background a `button` has.  For example, here is my pseudo code:

```
if (button background is `R.drawable.black`) {
  button.setBackground(to R.drawable.white)
}
```

Is there a way that this `if` statement can be done?  I know how to SET backgrounds, just curious on the test portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I believe that **tags** would be useful. Try this:

```
//When you set the button:
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
btn.setTag(R.drawable.black);


//When you re-set the button:
if(btn.getTag().equals(R.drawable.black)) {
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
    btn.setTag(R.drawable.white);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `getBackgroud` method

```
Drawable buttonBackground = button.getBackground();
```